# jquery selector: get both html content of the li object and the href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the below sample code for a navigation list:

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#sect1">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sect2">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sect3">link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

and some jquery code:
$("#menu li").click(function () {
  var mylicontent=$(this).html();
});
```

I want to get both html content of the li object and the href value.

Comment: just some comment on the markup: you can take out that extra div and put the id on your ul :) less markup, more semantic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like:

```
$("#menu li").click(function () {
  var mylicontent = $(this).html();
  var mylik = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Or you can also do like:

```
$("#menu li").click(function () {
  var mylicontent = $(this).html();
  var mylik = $('a', this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: I would use delegate here rather than x click events

Comment: delegate..., what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Nice! Sarfraz, a little suggestion in your first option we can take $(this) in a separate variable and can use that variable multiple times instead of doing $(this) again in that method.

Answer (score 2):

It's best if you attach click on the `a` and not on the `li`.

Then you'd do something like `$(this).parent().html()`